# Hide specific columns in jQuery Datatable according to some condition on response data

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have below code in which I want to hide certain columns on the basis of city data. 
I have used a callback function but it disrupts the table. 
Also it gives error if I change something in it.

```
var hide_col = $('#table_id').dataTable().api();
var table = $('#table_id');
var oTable = table.dataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/app/get-data/"+val1+'/'+val2+'/'+val3+'/',
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "paging": true,
    "columnDefs": [
        {"targets": 1, "orderable": false},{"targets": 2, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 3, "orderable": false},{"targets": 4, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 5, "orderable": false},{"targets": 6, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 7, "orderable": false},{"targets": 8, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 9, "orderable": false},{"targets": 10, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 11, "orderable": false},{"targets": 12, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 13, "orderable": false},{"targets": 14, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 15, "orderable": false},{"targets": 16, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 17, "orderable": false},{"targets": 18, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 19, "orderable": false},{"targets": 20, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 21, "orderable": false},{"targets": 22, "orderable": false},
        {"targets": 23, "orderable": false},{"targets": 24, "orderable": false},

        {"width": "200%", className: "dt-left", "targets": 0}
    ],

    buttons: [{ extend: 'print',
         className: 'btn dark btn-outline' },
        { extend: 'copy',
          className: 'btn red btn-outline' },
        { extend:'pdf',
          orientation:'landscape',
          className: 'btn green btn-outline',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] }},
        { extend: 'excel',
          className: 'btn yellow btn-outline' },
        { extend: 'csv',
          className: 'btn purple btn-outline' },
        { extend: 'colvis',
          className: 'btn dark btn-outline',
          text: 'Columns' }
    ],
    // setup responsive extension: http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/
    responsive: false,

    "order": [
        [0, 'asc']
    ],

    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 20, 50, 100],
        [10, 20, 50, 100]  // change per page values here] // change per page values here
    ],
    // set the initial value
    "pageLength": 10,

    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {            
        if (settings.jqXHR.responseJSON.city == 'A'){
            hide_col.columns([6,7,8,12,16,17,18,19,20]).visible(false);
            hide_col.columns([9,10,11,13,14,15,21,22,23,24]).visible(true);
        }
        else if (settings.jqXHR.responseJSON.city == 'B'){
            hide_col.columns([9,10,11,13,14,15,21,22,23,24]).visible(false);
            hide_col.columns([6,7,8,12,16,17,18,19,20]).visible(true);
        }
    }
});
```

I am using one callback too but seems I am doing something wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it disrupts the table"?

Comment: I agree,  I think @Luffy will need to provide more information for us to actually help you. You can set a column's visibility in the columnDefs with visibility: true/false, but it is not clear what your conditions are.

Comment: See, I have called one ajax which gives me a city and a list in response. So lets say if I got city 'A' in response then I will show 15 columns out of 30 and rest will hide. This goes same for city 'B' also. The columns which I need to hide and show are given in a callback "initComplete". This is the case and this is what I want to do.

Comment: Then show us what you have tried to do in your Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to access `Datatables API` before it's actually initialized. In fact, I believe you can get rid of `hide_col` variable at all and call [columns().visible(](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible())) using `oTable` variable.

So remove this line:

```
var hide_col = $('#table_id').dataTable().api();
```

And change this function to use `oTable` instead of `hide_col`:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {            
    if (settings.jqXHR.responseJSON.city == 'A'){
        oTable.columns([6,7,8,12,16,17,18,19,20]).visible(false);
        oTable.columns([9,10,11,13,14,15,21,22,23,24]).visible(true);
    }
    else if (settings.jqXHR.responseJSON.city == 'B'){
        oTable.columns([9,10,11,13,14,15,21,22,23,24]).visible(false);
        oTable.columns([6,7,8,12,16,17,18,19,20]).visible(true);
    }
}
```